# Qt - Closing the program from a QDialog (Before MainWindow fully loaded)

Tags: c++, qt

### INTRODUCTION

Hi. In my application, I run a QDialog before the constructor of the MainWindow finishes. Depending on the user input in this QDialog, I want to close the application.

### THE PROBLEM

I can't call `qApp->quit()` or `qApp->exit(int retcode = 0)` as the QApplication event loop haven't started. Is there a way I can force MainWindow to quit? Or maybe wait until it is fully loaded before quitting?

### SOLUTIONS?

I managed to make it work but I have no idea why. This is the .cpp of my QDialog at the moment:

```
    QFileInfo checkConfig(configPath);
    if(!checkConfig.exists() || !checkConfig.isFile())
    {
        qDebug() << "Sair!";
        qApp->quit();
        //qApp->exit(1);
        //QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit);
        QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }
```

Using `QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit)`, `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection)`, `qApp->quit()` or `qApp->exit(1)` did nothing.

But, for some reason, using ( `qApp->quit()` or `qApp->exit(1)` ) and ( `QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit)` or `QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection)` ) works!

I feel that using this solution can come back to bite me in the ass later, since I don't know how it is working. Does anyone have a better solution or an explanation?

### EDIT

Calling `QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit)` alone is not closing the application for me. Although, the second time I pass through the function, it does close. The `QTimer::singleShot()` is on a re implemented `QDialog::reject` method. And, before closing I show a `QMessageBox`. Any of this can interfere with the `QTimer`?

### EDIT 2

I ran the example @user3606329 show. It does indeed work. I went a few steps further and used my `QDialog` from the other program in this one. And it indeed did not work. So the problem is in my `QDialog`? Below is the entire `reject` method:

```
void Configuracao::reject()
{    
    QFileInfo checkConfig(configPath);
    if(!checkConfig.exists() || !checkConfig.isFile())
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Erro na configuração","Erro na criação do aquivo config.ini.\n"
                                                    "O programa será finalizado!");
        qDebug() << "Sair!";
        //qApp->quit();
        //qApp->exit(1);
        QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit);
        //QMetaObject::invokeMethod(qApp, "quit", Qt::QueuedConnection);
    }
}
```

### EDIT 3

I decided to create another `QDialog` and **ONLY** re implement the reject method with `QTimer::singleShot`. It still didn't work. The first time reject was called, it went through `QTimer::singleShot` and did nothing (Not even closed the Dialog). The second time, it closed the dialog and closed the application. Any ideas why? (Code below)

mainwindow.h:

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "dialog.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog *conf;
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    conf = new Dialog(this);
    conf->exec();
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

dialog.h:

```
#ifndef DIALOG_H
#define DIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>

namespace Ui {
class Dialog;
}

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;

protected:
    void reject();
};

#endif // DIALOG_H
```

dialog.cpp:

```
#include "dialog.h"
#include "ui_dialog.h"
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);

}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::reject()
{
    QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, []() {
        qDebug() << "QTimer done";
        QCoreApplication::quit();
    });
}
```

main.cpp:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    qDebug() << "Event loop started";
    return a.exec();
}
```

Output:

```
QTimer done //first click on "close window"
Event loop started //first click on "close window"
QTimer done //second click on "close window"
```

Comment: @ andseg The code you edited in 3 is working as expected. If the `QTimer` is not executed the Dialog will stay open so you call usually `this->reject` or `this->accept` when re-implementing `reject()`. Anyhow, I can confirm it does work without `reject` and `accept`. Try to add a `return;` or `accept()` or `reject()` under the `QTimer`. There is no error in your code and I must refer to my previous Résumé in my answer.

Comment: Calling `accept()` works, but will change the return of `exec()`. Calling `return;` does nothing. Finally, calling `reject()` creates a loop and break the code. I will test with around `done()` or `close()`.

Comment: @ andseg `conf->exec() should block` the main event loop until the dialog is closed. `conf->show()` should immediately close as the main event loop is not blocked and can recieve `quit()`

Comment: Sorry, `accept()` does not change the return of `exec()`. But shouldn't they be different types of return?

Comment: @user3606329 Yes, I thought about using `show()`. But I want to block all interactions until the conf window is resolved. With `conf->show()`, the user can minimize the window and not do the important setup.

Comment: @ andseg: If you use `exec()` you must call a function that closes the QDialog or the main event loop cannot proceed with `quit()`. Also it's not good to put the QTimer in the virtual function, better you connect it to one of the signals `rejected()`, `finished()`, `accepted()` `connect(this, &QDialog::accepted, []() {  qDebug() << "accepted"; });
    connect(this, &QDialog::finished, []() {  qDebug() << "finished"; });`

Comment: By using `done(0)`, it simulates a reject right? `done(int r)` will return the return code r (which for reject, it is 0). I tried using it on the end of my reject re implementation. So far it is working (and looks like a good solution that won't cause future problems).

Comment: `done(int result)` will return the result which is handled by your code. It acts like accept() and closes the Dialog. It can return 0 for reject, or 1 for accept. It's a custom implementation.

Comment: When it's working for you, accept my answer please.

Comment: I will use the `done`solution. It seems to be working. Thank you for the help.

Comment: Yes, that should work. Also it's better to use `connect(this, &QDialog::finished, [](int r) { EXIT APP });` instead of placing the code in  `reject()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code

```
QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, &QCoreApplication::quit)
```

will queue [quit()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qcoreapplication.html#quit) and execute it when the event loop is started. Nothing else is required. You can take a look at this small example:

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTimer>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();

    QTimer::singleShot(0, qApp, []() { 
         qDebug() << "Event loop started"; 
         QCoreApplication::quit(); 
    });


    return a.exec(); // QCoreApplication::quit() is executed after the call
}
```

Running the following code before the event loop starts

```
qApp->quit() or qApp->exit(1)
```

will not have any effect to your application.

***Résumé***

It appears that you have either not placed the the code correctly in your editor or you left out important parts in your question. I suggest you create a simple application with my above code example.

Comment: Maybe you´re right and I messed something up in my code. I will make an EDIT in the question

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <QShowEvent>
#include <QDebug>
...
protected:
    ...
    void showEvent(QShowEvent *event);
    ...
private:
    ...
    bool init_check = false;
    ...


void MainWindow::showEvent(QShowEvent *event){
    qDebug() << "QShowEvent" << init_check;

    if(!init_check){
        init_check = true;
        bool err = true;
        if(err){
            qDebug() << "Closing app";
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't be sorry. Overriding showEvent is also a possible solution.

Comment: I upvoted you, although I wouldn't use your solution :) (too complicated imho).